# Magento - locate specific core files

Tags: php, templates, magento, module

I am familiar with theming and using template hints in the Magento back office to locate .phtml files.

What I am not really familiar with are the core files such as app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model

What I need to do is override a core file like I would a core phtml file by copying it to 'my theme'.

I basically want to amend some labels which appear on the order summary page of the Magento checkout process - domain.com/checkout/cart/

I followed the trail to the phtml files using template hints. Within the app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/template/checkout/cart I found the code

renderTotals(); ?>

Now I managed, by accident, to stumble upon two of the files I wanted to change:

/httpdocs/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Grand.php
/httpdocs/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Shipping.php

I made local copies of these files (http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/how_to/how_to_create_a_local_copy_of_app_code_core_mage) to override the default labels, like I would if I was overriding a template file.

My question is, how can you locate core files which pertain to the 'stuff' you want to change, located in function calls such as renderTotals(); ?> in the phtml files?

Not being able to pinpoint stuff like I can with template hints is slowing me down, and I am struggling to find a solution as I am not up on all the vocab surrounding Magento yet.

Hope this makes sense and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

From the same settings page where you turn on Template Path Hints, also turn on the "**Add Block Names to Hints**" setting.  This will show you PHP class names such as: `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Grand` to which you can deduce the folder path (underscores represent a subfolder, and the last piece represents the file name).

If you're getting a block such as `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Default` then sometimes it just takes a little common sense to see that it's pulling in other files from the same folder (such as `Grand.php` and `Shipping.php`).  But there are generally only a couple files in the same folder, so this is pretty easy to see.

As Sid Vel said, a good Search Project functionality is helpful. But if you find yourself looking at Abstract.php of some class, often you need to look in a subfolder in that directory with the proper name to find the concrete implementations.  But still, it gets you very close to where you need to be.

Comment: Hi Philfreo,

Thanks for your reply!

I am not sure if it is because I am using a legacy magento system (1.2.X), but the block hints only supply a generic block path like: Mage_Checkout_Block_Total_Default - this is for the Grand & Shipping totals, and as I said I kind of stumbled upon them by accident.


I know this is a big ask, but any ideas how I can determine the block paths without block hints? 

Thanks again!

Comment: First of all, I would always strongly recommend not getting very far behind in Magento versions.  They fix a huge number of bugs each revision, and if you're doing you're theming and functionality changes properly (not changing core files) than updates should be very easy to do.  

I've updated my original answer to provide more detail based on your comment here.

Answer (score 0):

I always use Dreamweaver's site / directory search function. It will scan through all the files in the Core folder and tell you where the function is from. In your case, I would search for "renderTotals". You need to enable PHTML editing in Dreamweaver.

Most IDE's will allow this kind of search option. In Aptana you can Ctrl + Click on the function to open the file it is coming from. Magento takes ages to index itself on Aptana, due to its sheer size.

Comment: I would suggest this as the best way to trace back to the file that contains the function that you are looking for.

Comment: I love Aptana's Ctrl+Click (or hit F3 when the cursor is on the function name), however this actually fails quite frequently in the Magento framework.  The reason is that it often it will open up the interface or abstract version of the class, when really you're wanting a concrete subclass or implementation.  But it's still helpful to get you close, just remember often if it opens an Abstract.php to look for the concrete versions of the same class.